# Merge [virtual-method] into [virtual-functions]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Tag [virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-method) (137) looks to me identical to [virtual-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) (473).

They both have similar wikis:

> A virtual method is a method whose behavior can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature.

And,

> In object-oriented programming, a virtual function or virtual method is a function or method whose behaviour can be overridden within an inheriting class by a function with the same signature. This concept is a very important part of the polymorphism portion of object-oriented programming (OOP).

The only difference is that first named in .NET terms, second - in general OOP.

More candidates to future synonym family: [virtual-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-methods) and [virtual-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-function).

Comment: [virtual-functions] is a C++ tag.  Cats-and-dogs with any language that uses the word "method", don't do this.

Comment: And C#. And F# too. So I'd say it's OOP tag. Their wikis are identical, just different phrasing.

Comment: @UphillLuge What do you mean by "don't do this?" Don't merge the tags? Or don't use the [virtual-functions] tag? Also, what do you mean by "cats and dogs"?

Comment: It is the people that are not identical.  C++ users have *very* little patience with C# and Java questions.

Comment: @HansPassant: Actually, it's a crapshot whether it's tagged with virtual-functions or virtual-methods. Anyway, they denote the exact same concept imho, so merging / synonymizing should be appropriate.

Comment: @Hans: Let's have separate tag for each term just because C++ people are 'special'.

Comment: @HansPassant that's what [c++] and [java] tags are for. I see no reason why these tags can't be merged, since there will always be a language tag for any question that relates to a specific language.