# Inconsistent use of [virtual] on C++ questions

Tags: discussion, tags

The [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) tag is described as "An extensible or simulated artifact" , and the Tag Wiki gives four possible use cases: "virtual memory", "virtual hard disk", "virtual method", and "virtual reality".

The following tags already exist and cover all of the uses of the C++ `virtual` keyword:

- [virtual-destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-destructor)
- [virtual-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-functions)
- [virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-method) ([arguable!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250917/merge-virtual-method-into-virtual-functions))
- [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vtable)

However, searching for questions using these tags results in a mishmash, for example:

- Searching [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) will not find questions tagged [virtual-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-functions)
- Searching [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) will find stuff like VR helmet code, virtual memory etc., which gets in the way if you're looking for info on virtual functions
- Searching [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[virtual-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) won't find questions about virtual functions that have only been tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual)
- Searching [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)[virtual*] will not find questions tagged [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vtable)

To fix this I'd like to suggest a tagging policy:

- all C++ questions which currently have [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) have one of the above tags added also
- Add [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) to all of these questions (or remove it from all!)
- [virtual-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-table) be set as a synonym for [vtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vtable)

Comment: I'm not sure if there is much more expertise overlap than chance dictates between virtual reality and virtual destructors.

Comment: C++ also has virtual inheritance. I doubt whether just [tag:virtual] alone is a useful tag.

Comment: I would argue for `vtable` to be a synonym of `virtual-table`, since the former is a contraction of the latter.

Comment: Maybe there should also be a virtual-interview-tick-question…

Comment: IMO `vtable`, `virtual-table`, `virtual-function`, `virtual-method` should all be aliased to [tag:virtual-dispatch]