# This tag is [virtual]ly useless

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

This question is a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) and is different from existing questions.

#### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

The [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual) tag has over 2K questions, *each* is, to some extent, *related* to a technology whose name contains the word "virtual", like [virtualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualization), [virtual-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory), [virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality), et cetera.

The ambiguity of this tag has been discussed before:

- [[virtual]ly useless catch-all tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/364411)
- [Inconsistent use of [virtual] on C++ questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275553)

Ambiguous? Just read [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/virtual/info) and you'll have the answer!

#### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Given its high ambiguity, I'm hesitant towards answering this question. It appears like that *some* are on-topic while *some* others are not, like management of virtual machines [vmware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vmware) [virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox).

#### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Hardly any yes. This tag adds nothing but an extra layer of ambiguity when there already exist other more suitable and more specific tags, as mentioned above.

#### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

*(repeated content not displayed)*

---

Given the answers above, I think this tag is a good candidate for next burnination. What do you think?

Comment: For the record, I'm briefly cleaning up this tag by editing, retagging salvageable questions and CV-ing bad ones.

Comment: WRT whether this is on-topic or not: it seems like this criteria doesn't exactly apply because it's ambiguous to the point that we don't know what topic it's even referring to in the first place.

Comment: About all keywords in a language have a dedicated tag.  Not useless, it is what newbie programmers struggle with.  Especially so for [virtual], object-oriented programming stumps even the not-so-newbie programmers.  Such questions may well be useless to you, bit of a yawn after you figured it out.  In which case you *definitely* don't want the tag burninated, you want to add it to the Ignored Tags section of your profile so you'll never have to look at them again.

Comment: @HansPassant Then what about the current ambiguity of the tag? Leave it alone?

Comment: I is never ambiguous to me when I see it used on a question.  Along with the language tag, like [c++].  Keywords in a language were meant to not be ambiguous.  No idea why it would be to anybody else, sorry.

Comment: Good thing Hans identified it's current use: keyword. Tags are not keywords, nor hashtags, but well *defined* categories. Keywords are for the search engine to figure it out using the whole body of the question.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your interest in this question. Would you mind writing your defense into an answer?

Comment: Not really, it is a job much better done by one of the 245 SO users that watch the tag.  Or users like Lucian Grigore or David Rodriguez that have a substantial number of answers in the tag.  Not that this is very likely to happen, these kind of braiamian potshots are no fun to the kind of users that don't mind helping out newbies.  Just give them a break.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, fine. Thanks anyway. I take your words.

Comment: For C++, it should definitely be always be removed in favor of one of: [tag:virtual-destructor], [tag:virtual-method] = [tag:virtual-functions], [tag:virtual-inheritance], [tag:virtual-table] = [tag:vtable]. Those `=`s need to be made synonyms.

Comment: @Braiam: HansPassant wasn't referring to keywords as in search engine optimization, but rather a part of the c++ programming language. See [Microsoft's Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/virtual-cpp) & [CPP Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/virtual) for more info.

Comment: @3D1T0R "Keywords in a *language*" he never said that it was in a specific language. Also, keywords has different meanings in many language, see `for`. BTW, I wasn't specifying what he meant, but what it implied.

Comment: @Braiam: He never said anything about SEO, he may not have specifically meant the keyword in C++, as it can also be used for the same keyword in other languages, and should (as he stated) be tagged with the appropriate language as well, but he did state that he meant *a keyword in a language*, and then he [gave C++ as an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374164/this-tag-is-virtually-useless?noredirect=1#comment630817_374164), which definitively means that SEO is NOT what he was referring to.

Comment: @HansPassant How do you know it's usage is for a keyword? You certainly can't tell that from the tag name. I'd put a small amount of money on finding questions tagged [tag:virtual] [tag:memory] (at least prior to iBug's clean up). [Looks like I'd win.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual+memory) 
The description also says nothing about the keyword. If I were looking at a C++ question, the tag would certainly not tell me it's about the `virtual` keyword as opposed to memory. Thus it adds no useful information.

Comment: Both vmware and virtualbox are tools used by programmers.  There are highly specific programming related issues, like remote debugging in a virtual box, differences in how the video device works, and a few other categories.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont But then the tag should be either `vmware` or `virtualbox` not `virtual`. I agree with @HansPassant. If we start removing those keywords and new programmers come to the site they most likely won't know if `virtual` refers to a function, ... 
Furthermore we'd then have to discuss other keyword-tags e.g. `abstract`.

Comment: @jAC OP stated that the vmware and virtualbox tags are off-topic in a sentence.  I was disputing that.

Answer (score 3):

Retag and burninate. Most of the tag's uses are on-topic but they can't be distinguished from each other even taking all the other tags into account.

Likely tags:

[virtual-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-methods) for virtual functions (C++) or methods (other languages); hey; [virtual-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-functions) -> [virtual-methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-methods) is a great alias. Some questions might also need [abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/abstract)

[virtual-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-properties) for the same idea with properties in the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) family

[virtulization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtulization) for how to make something run in a virtual machine environment

[virtual-machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machines) for all other VM questions.

[virtual-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-memory) for questions involving virtual memory mapping

[paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/paging) for memory being paged to disk

[virtual-reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-reality) for the obvious reason

[virtual-destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-destructor) for questions about destructors in C++ that already have the virtual tag.

[framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/framebuffer) for off-screen rendering (yes somebody really did tag one [virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual)

[virtual-filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtual-filesystem) for the obvious (tag does not yet exist)

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down votes while it supports the burnination and guidance on how to retag / cleanup during the burn. Am I missing something why this answer isn't any good?

Comment: @rene: probably fans of the virtual tag. Shrug. The community does what it wants.

Comment: Or maybe that many of the proposed new tags also are problematic. Probably people just want to remove [virtual] not replace it with other tags.

Comment: @Braiam: Considering all but one of the proposed cleanup targets already exists ...